# Tokenising and reconstructing a string containing delimited name-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, implode

I have a string structured as such:

```
 "01;AA:02;AB:03;AC:"
```

is there a way to make it into a $_POST style format where:

```
 $MyVar['01'] = "AA"
 $MyVar['02'] = "AB"
 $MyVar['03'] = "AC"
```

?

i would also like to somehow implode it back into the original string format when i'm done with changes. (leading zero's not necessary on implode, and may not be there when exploding)

edit: adding information

```
 InevntorySKU;InventoryQTY:
     086;99:043;99:130;99:131;99:132;99:133;99:134;99:135;99:136;99:137;99:138;99:139;99:140;99:141;99:142;99:143;99:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this, but you could do it like so:

```
$MyVar = array();
foreach(array_filter(explode(":",$input)) as $i) {
    list($k,$v) = explode(";",$i,2);
    $MyVar[$k] = $v;
}
```

You would use a similar setup for the reverse process:

```
$output = "";
foreach($MyVar as $k=>$v) $output .= $k.";".$v.":";
```

Comment: Problem - knowing ahead of time what the $K is for recall, in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('/\d{2}|[a-z]{2}/i', "01;AA:02;AB:03;AC:", $array);

for($i=0;$i<count($array[0]);$i+=2){
    $myvar[$array[0][$i]] = $array[0][$i+1];
}

print_r($myvar);
```

---

Using preg_split:

```
$str = '086;99:043;99:130;99:131;99:132;99:133;99:134;99:135;99:136;99:137;99:138;99:139;99:140;99:141;99:142;99:143;99:';
$array = preg_split('/;|:/', $str);

for($i=0;$i<count($array)-1;$i+=2){
    $myvar[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
}

print_r($myvar);
```